# Having trouble moving subdirectories meeting certain criteria into related folders.

Tags: powershell

The folder structure I am working with looks like this:

```
-Clients
 -Walmart
   -00001
   -00001
   -00001
   -00001
   -Letters
   -Numbers

 -Lowes
   -00001
   -00001
   -00001
   -00001
   -Letters
   -Numbers
```

In each subfolder of the Clients directory (Walmart & Lowes in this case), I would like to take every folder that contains a number in its name and move it to the "Numbers" subfolder.

So far, I have managed to put this together:

```
$source = "Clients"
$dirs = dir $source
foreach ($folder in $dirs) | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\d"}
{
    Move -Destination $folder\Numbers
}
```

But this didn't work, which I expected. For some reason, I am having a hard time finding exactly how to tell it what my Destination is. What is the best way to approach this? Am I missing something simple or making it harder than it needs to be? I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: While I am fairly sure what your issue is in this case _But this didn't work_ it not a descriptive problem. I am sure that you got errors at least that should be included here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` snippet is misplaced and syntactically incorrect. It should be inside the loop checking each clients sub-directories for matches. Couple of other options are available to you but this one should do the trick.

```
$source = "Clients"
# Get all the clients 
$clients = Get-ChildItem $source -Directory

# Traverse each clients folder looking for mumbers 
$clients | ForEach-Object{
    $clientFolder = $_
    Get-ChildItem $clientFolder.FullName -Directory | 
        Where-Object{$_.Name -match "\d"} | 
        Move-Item "$clientFolder\Numbers" 
}
```

We don't check that the `-destination` exists so that could be a source of errors. If they always exist then you should not have to worry. Still a good practice just in case.

```
$clientNumbersFolder = "$clientFolder\Numbers"
If(-not Test-Path $clientNumbersFolder){New-Item -Path $clientNumbersFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null}
Move-Item "$clientFolder\Numbers"
```